# I would like chapter headings in all caps

Tags: titlecaps

I am using a template ( ARIZONA STATE UNIVERSITY) to write a thesis that uses a .sty file, and would like the chapter headings for example I want "CHAPTER 1" and not "Chapter 1" for each section to be in all caps. I am making changes to the .sty file but nothing happens. I've included the entire .sty file code and I want to where I can make my adjustments.

```
 \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                \else
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                \fi
                \chaptermark{#1}%

                %These two lines below are commented out.

                %\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                %\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                \if@twocolumn
                  \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                \else
                  \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                  \@afterheading
                \fi}

      %
   % Change some of the rules for float placement.
  %
 \setcounter{topnumber}{2}          %Maximum 2 floats on top
 \setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}       %Maximum 1 float on bottom
%\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.7}    %Top float max size is 70%
%\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.7} %Bottom float max size is 70%
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.9}    %Top float max size is 70%
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.8} %Bottom float max size is 70%
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}


       %
      % Fix chapter and section formats
      %
       % Chapters names are all caps, centered under "Chapter N"
       \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
       \begin{center}
     \chaptername\ \thechapter\vspace{\baselineskip}\\
      \uppercase\expandafter{#1}\vspace{\baselineskip}
      \end{center}
   }
        % Numbers chapters, sections, and subsections
      \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
      % Center section titles
       \renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0 in}{1em}{1em}
   {\centering}}
   % Center and italicize subsection titles
  \renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0 in}{1em}{1em}
   {\centering\slshape}}
```

Comment: Welcome! But what can we say beyond 'there is something wrong with the changes you are making or something elsewhere which undoes them or you forgot to recompile'? We need to see the code you're having trouble with, preferably in the form of a small document we can compile to reproduce the nothing which happens when you compile it yourself.

Comment: `CHAPTER` is set via `\chaptername`, which you leave unchanged. You could do `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}`.

Comment: Where can we find the template? Are you allowed to change it?

Comment: It's the Arizona State University thesis template

Comment: If you found a fix, go ahead and answer your own question, for the benefit of others who may stumble onto this question in the future, please.

Comment: You mentioned in the question the name of the template, but no link. There are millions of thesis templates out there. Some universities have more than one template.

Comment: The thesis template link https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/arizona-state-university-phd-dissertation

Comment: I may have written that I found a fix for this, but it was for another post, the answer that was given by Werner is what I used to remedy this problem

Comment: Is just the word "Chapter" supposed to be rendered in all-caps, or should the chapter header itself ("Introduction", "Concluding Remarks") be rendered in all-caps as well?

Answer (score 4):

In order to change the chapter name from `Chapter` to `CHAPTER`, you can issue

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
```

in the preamble.